# How to delete/disable user through slack API?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I have tried multiple approaches to this. Tried first getting the user without any user id - this returns me just my user, then tried getting user with other id's and it also retrieves data correctly. However, I can't seem to be able to set user attribute 'deleted'. i'm using this python approach.

```
slack_client.api_call('users.profile.set', deleted=True, user='U36D86MNK')
```

However I get the error message of:

```
{u'error': u'invalid_user', u'ok': False}
```

Maybe someone has already done this? It says in documentation that it's a paid service mentioning this message under a user property:

> This argument may only be specified by team admins on paid teams.

But shouldn't it give me a 'paid service' response in that case then?

Answer (score 4):

The [`users.profile.set`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set) apparently does not work for for setting each and every property of a user.

To set the `deleted` property there is another API method called [`users.admin.setInactive`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.setInactive.md). Its an undocumented method and it will only work on paid teams.

**Note**: This requires a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/legacy/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) and doesn't work with App tokens - these are only available on paid plans and *new legacy tokens can't be created anymore*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you happen to know if this command works on both plans (Standard and Plus) or only the more expensive one?

Comment: Idk. but I would assume it works on any paid plan. If you need to be sure I would suggest sending a mail to the Slack support team. They are very helpful.

Comment: Awesome! I joined their slack team of bot building. I tried using this method you mentioned, also came up to your github repo with that method explained, but currently the api response says that I need a client scope enabled, but when I look for it on the permission scopes but it doesn't exist..

Comment: @Zigmas You need a legacy token to get the client scope.

Answer (score 0):

in python you can do the following:

```
import requests

def del_slack_user(user_id): # the user_id can be found under get_slack_users()
    key = 'TOKEN KEY' #replace token key with your actual token key
    payload = {'token': key, 'user': user_id}
    response = requests.delete('https://slack.com/api/users.admin.setInactive', params=payload)
    print(response.content)

def get_slack_users():
    url = 'https://slack.com/api/users.list?token=ACCESSTOKEN&pretty=1'
    response = requests.get(url=url)
    response_data = response.json() # turns the query into a json object to search through`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Slack's [SCIM API](https://api.slack.com/scim#users) to enable and disable a user. Note that, as with the undocumented API endpoint mentioned in other answers this requires a Plus/Enterprise account.

Comment: Hi dsummersl , how to write GET rest query in c# for SCIM api.

Answer (score 0):

The deactivation "API" is not available to the public. You pretty much have to load up the slack admin page and grab the credential token and figure out what AJAX call to hit.

I just wrote a chrome extension to do that.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-slack-user-deactivat/bbklkhjijobpamjeemohloddompcehkc

Let me know if you run into any issues.